# How do I record partial payments?

Tags: civicontribute, contributions

My client frequently needs to record  partial payments for events and memberships. When I open the transaction history, I  don't see a way to record the partial payment. In fact, all registrations seem to get recorded as completed by default. Any suggestions for a workflow which better records the transactions and the status of payments?

Comment: Sounds like a workflow problem as well. Are people signing themselves up, or are these being manually added by someone with the organization? Because until they are fully paid, registrations should be something like pending, pending (pay later), partially paid, etc.

Answer (score 4):

- First, record the payment with a status of *Pending*.
- Click the triangle next to the contribution to open up the payment listing (see screenshot below).
- Click **Record Payment** (or **Submit Credit Card Payment**).  You can log a partial payment from here.

In my screenshot below, you can see the $55 donation has a status of "Partially Paid".

[image]